# How to remove the surroundings parenthesis from a String | Swift

Tags: swift

Why does code print with surrounding parenthesis and with the prefix int or string?
For example:

```
code: string("Gate: 2312231")
```

How can I just have it print `code: 2312231` and nothing more? Try the following code in Playgrounds to see the the printed values. I appreciate the help, let me know if there are any questions.

```
let data = """
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 122312,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

enum Code: Decodable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var code: Code
    var notes: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, code, notes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        self.notes = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .int(value)
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .string(value)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unable to decode value for `code`")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Code.self, context)
        }
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let items = try! decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)

for item in items {
    print("date: \(item.date.description)")
    print("code: \(item.code)")
    print("notes: \(item.notes)")
    print()
}
```

Comment: Why did you expect 2312231 only? Shouldn't "Gate: " also be included? That whole thing is the entire string, isn't it?

Comment: Yes apologies, the desired result is `code: Gate: 2312231`

Comment: It's printing the `int` or `string` prefix because your `Code` type is an enum with associated values, and `int` and `string` are the name of its cases. If you want to print just the int, or just the string, then you need to read those associated values out and use them directly.

Comment: Understood, how can the associated values be read out and used?

Comment: Not related to your question but your DateFormatter is very error prone

Comment: Btw you are force unwrapping the try keyword. If anything goes wrong  (and it will for sure) it will crash your app. You should always handle the errors thrown.

Comment: @StephanieSmith Check out https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148

Comment: I'm not sure this de-duplicatation is accurate. The solution here is to probably to unwrap these values and handle them properly, not just to override `description` in a way that plasters over the mistake

Comment: Can you please show an example, I would really appreciate it